# JavaScript loading circle using `<source>`

Tags: javascript, html, css, progress-bar

I have been asked to implement a loading circle for an internet connection test.

iv has been given an example of what is asked of me:

[image: (picture of requested loading circle)]

I am new to Javascript and web development and am trying to look good for the boss by saving time on this specific project by not create the circle from scratch. can someone provide a link to a "respectable website" that provides a `<source>`?

Comment: Source? That only displays multi-media formats. Are you sure?

Comment: you may take some idea from https://www.jqueryscript.net/blog/best-circular-radial-progress-bar.html